# Swift Error: 'EnumName' has a raw type that depends on itself

Tags: swift, xcode, enums, compiler-errors

I am working on a old code base of a Swift iOS app (build by another developer). Last week there were no issues, but seems like after the last XCode update (11.4 (11E146)) I am unable to build the project because of an error (example given below):

```
'CarBrand' has a raw type that depends on itself
```

Everywhere throughout the project the library EnumList is being used... it seems like it is causing the issue.
(https://github.com/polac24/EnumList)

Here is an example of what the code looks like:

```
import Foundation
import EnumList

enum CarBrand: EnumListStringRaw<CarBrand.Values>, RawRepresentable {
    struct Values: StringEnumValues {
        typealias Element = CarBrand
        static var allRaws:Set<String> = []
    }

    case AUD = "Audi AG"
    case BMW = "Bayerische Motoren Werke AG"
    case MERC = "Mercedes-Benz"
}
```

This enum is then used in a number of places (for example in a table view) like so:

```
let brandsList = Array(CarBrand.Values.all)
cell.textLabel?.text = brandsList[indexPath.row].rawValue.value
```

Since there are **a lot** of these errors and some of the enums are relatively large I was wondering if there is a quick fix or a workaround for this? Or will I have to re-code all of the enums and all the files that implement them?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received this solution from the EnumList library creator on GitHub and thought posting it here may help someone else along the way.
This solution is very quick and **does not require any code rewriting** for the enums or their implementations.

```
import Foundation
import EnumList

extension CarBrand{}

enum CarBrand: EnumListStringRaw<CarBrand.Values>, RawRepresentable {
    struct Values: StringEnumValues {
        typealias Element = CarBrand
        static var allRaws:Set<String> = []
    }

    case AUD = "Audi AG"
    case BMW = "Bayerische Motoren Werke AG"
    case MERC = "Mercedes-Benz"
}
```

Simply adding the empty "extension CarBrand{}" seems to fix the Swift compiler issue!

Link to the original answer I received on GitHub:
https://github.com/polac24/EnumList/issues/5

Thank you to library creator for the support!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a third party library to iterate through enum cases (seems like overkill).

Just have your CarBrand enum use the `CaseIterable` protocol, like this:

```
enum CarBrand: String, RawRepresentable, CaseIterable {
    case AUD = "Audi AG"
    case BMW = "Bayerische Motoren Werke AG"
    case MERC = "Mercedes-Benz"
}
```

Now you can go through all enums like this:

`let allCarBrands = CarBrand.allCases`

Comment: Please read the question... This is an old code that was not made by me... the using of enums in a lot of places is overkill itself, not to mention the usage of the library yes... My question was about the error I was getting and if there is a way to fix it WITHOUT rewriting all of the code as this type of enums are used extensively throughout the whole app.

Comment: You asked if there was a quick fix or workaround for this, and I gave that. I think fixing these enums to not use a 3p library will save you headache in the future. Every time you upgrade the OS, you will have a potential issue with the library not being updated.